# Package nar with docker maven image?

Tags: docker, maven, apache-nifi

Tell in advance - I'm not a java/maven/linux developer/user.

I have a github project I need to build and package - https://github.com/simonellistonball/nifi-webdav-bundle with provided instruction https://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_nifi/apache_nifi_custom_processor.htm. But I don't understand how to solve this with docker image https://hub.docker.com/_/maven. In my environment I have CentOS VM with git and docker installed.

My plan is: git clone repo into host VM, create docker volume, copy repo there, run container with some params (dunno which exact) and remove container.
Am I thinking right way? Is it even possible with maven container without creating my own image?

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices:

1. Map `/opt/nifi/nifi-current/extensions` in the container to the host and drop the nar there.
2. Add a `Dockerfile` that looks something like this:

```
FROM apache/nifi:1.12.1

COPY --chown=nifi ./something.nar /opt/nifi/nifi-current/lib/something.nar
```

Comment: Thank you for reply, but my first trouble is to build that 3rd party project into nar. I thought I ‘d be able to do this with Maven container passing params to it.

Comment: You said "I'm not a java/maven/linux developer/user." Unfortunately, you need to have some decent Java, Maven and Linux (or Docker) skills to get this done.

Comment: I tried 'docker run -it --rm --name maven-nifi-webdav-bundle -v /git/public-repo/nifi-webdav-bundle:/usr/src/mymaven -w /usr/src/mymaven/nifi-webdav-bundle/nifi-webdav-processors maven mvn clean install' but it gives me an error 'there is no pom in this directory'. Not sure how to make .nar from the source.

Comment: You have to create a new Docker image that inherits from the Maven image, copies the code inside, runs Maven there and then layer on a new base image. What you're asking to do here is doable, but it's intermediate level Docker.

Comment: I can map volume to maven container, but I can't build (or package) project to .nar. It tells me there is no pom file. I will try a few more times before throw my idea away.